# How do i pass parameters as well as set headers with rest_client in http api call

Tags: ruby, json, rest-client

With rest_client gem

I have to pass parametes and set http headers as well. 
parameters-
 {"module"=>{"id"=>376373}, "name"=>"test workflow", "playbooks"=>[{"name"=>"shell_book.yml"}]}
headers- 
{Accept => application/json, content-type => application/json, mode => agentless}

please suggest how do i do this.

My code looks like this-
RestClient.put(@@host+'/workflow/agentless', {:params =>  {"module"=>{"id"=>376373}, "name"=>"test workflow", "playbooks"=>[{"name"=>"shell_book.yml"}]}
})

Comment: I tried
  RestClient::Request.execute(
   :method => :put,
   :url => @@host+'/workflow/agentless',
   :params => params,
   :headers => {"content_type" => "application/json", "accept" => "application/json", "mode" => "agentless"})
Its throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter is the [headers hash](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb#L79).

Try the code below with your values:

```
response = RestClient.put(url, request, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing params.to_json earlier... following worked for me.

RestClient.put(@@host+'/workflow/agentless', params.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json, :mode => :agentless)